# Logback will only log a message to syslog once

Tags: java, logback, syslog

I've tried several examples of using logback to write to syslog, but the only that I've found that works is this [JavaCodeGeeks example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/logback/logback-syslog-example/).  It writes a message to syslog, but it only writes a message once no matter how many times I run the code.  If I change the message it will write it to syslog, but only once.

I'm on Ubuntu 19.10.  I've uncommented the following four lines from my /etc/rsyslog.conf and restarted :

```
# provides UDP syslog reception
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")

# provides TCP syslog reception
module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514")
```

The only change I made to the javacodegeeks code is to comment out the remote appender in `logback.xml`.  It only logs to the localhost syslog.

What causes this weird behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To log all messages you have to set

```
$RepeatedMsgReduction off
```

in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and restart rsyslog.

https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/action/rsconf1_repeatedmsgreduction.html

The default was `on` in Ubuntu 19.10.